# Scatter-gather: combine set of Mono<List<Item>> into single Mono<List<Item>>

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, java-9, spring-webflux

Can I combine a list of `Mono<List<Item>>` data sources into a single `Mono<List<Item>>` containing all items without blocking?

In my JDK 9 Spring Boot 2 with Lombok scatter-gather application, this blocking version works:

```
    private Mono<List<Item>> gather(List<Mono<List<Item>>> data) {
        return Mono.just( data.stream().map(m -> m.block())
                .flatMap(List::parallelStream).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

Each source data stream invokes `block()` on its `Mono`; I'd like to reduce the `block()` calls if possible...preferably to zero. Any ideas?

**Test case**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ReactiveTests {
    @Test
    public void testScatterGather() {
        List<List<Item>> dataSet = dataSet();
        Mono<List<Item>> data = gather(scatter(dataSet));
        StepVerifier.create(data)
            .expectNext(toItemList(dataSet))
            .expectComplete();
    }

    private Mono<List<Item>> gather(List<Mono<List<Item>>> data) {
        return Mono.just( data.stream().map(m -> m.block())
                .flatMap(List::parallelStream).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    private List<Mono<List<Item>>> scatter(List<List<Item>> data) {
        return newMonoLists(data);
    }

    private List<Item> toItemList(List<List<Item>> data) {
        return data.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<Mono<List<Item>>> newMonoLists(List<List<Item>> data) {
        return data.stream().map(l -> Mono.just(l)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<List<Item>> dataSet() {
        return Arrays.asList(dataSet(1L),dataSet(4L),dataSet(7L));
    }

    private List<Item> dataSet(long id) {
        return Arrays.asList(new Item(id), new Item(id+1), new Item(id+2));
    }
    @Data @AllArgsConstructor private static class Item { private Long id; }
}
```

Comment: [Using Flux might be of help](https://dzone.com/articles/scatter-gather-using-spring-reactor-core)?

Comment: Are you thinking of `Flux.merge`, @nullpointer? I was expecting something like a merge operation but I haven't found a way, yet.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have 2 Mono sources having a List of String.

```
Mono<List<String>> listMono1 = Mono.just(Arrays.asList("1","3","5","7","9","11"));
Mono<List<String>> listMono2 = Mono.just(Arrays.asList("2","4","6","8","10","12"));
```

You can merge two publishers using the method [Flux.merge()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) which takes in a bunch of publishers and merges them together.

But if you merge both the publishers  like below, then it will finally give you `List<List<String>>`  , which you don't  want.

```
Flux.merge(listMono1, listMono2).collectList();
```

So you have to modify the listMono1 and listMono2 such that they emit individual elements of the List and then merge both of them. To do that you can use [Mono.flatMapMany()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-) which will help you emit all the elements from the List. So, finally you will get the combined List as follows:

```
Flux.merge(listMono1.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable),listMono2.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)).collectList();
```

Hope its what you want finally!